# iOS WKWebView Audio only plays once

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, wkwebview

I'm using

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="^1.1.4" />
```

with Cordova@7.1 + iOS@5.0.0

I have set my preferences to

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

In the js code of my page I play a sound (once loaded) but this **only works the first time**

```
 (...)on('touchstart', function(){
     snd.play();
 });
```

snd is a Audio object that has been preloaded. **The code works fine on Chrome and Android Webview**, everytime I touch it plays my sound.

**But it only plays once on iOS WKWebView**, any further touchstart won't play the sound. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer so I'm posting it back. iOS webview only allows one sound at a time and from my tests, it appears the resource has to be reloaded once ended.

```
function onSoundEnded(){
    snd = new Audio();
    snd.addEventListener('ended', onSoundEnded, false);
    snd.src = 'snd/click.mp3';
}

onSoundEnded();
```